# Trying to store email address as a key in firebase database but getting this error:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store email address and password into firebase, and i wish to store email address as primary key but the app crash and show :

> Invalid Firebase Database path: ccw@qq.com. Firebase Database paths
>   must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

```
    private DatabaseReference Userdatabase;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";

    EditText nameText, addressText, emailText, mobileText, passwordText, reEnterPasswordText;
    Button signupButton;
    TextView loginLink;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        addressText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_address);
        emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        mobileText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        reEnterPasswordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_reEnterPassword);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        loginLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_login);

        Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");}


    public void AddUser(final String UserEmail, final String Username, final String Password,
                        final String PhoneNumber, final String ComfirmPassword
    , final String Address) {

        Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(UserEmail);
        Userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Username : " + Username + " Had Already Exist");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                return;
            }
        });

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail,Password).addOnCompleteListener(new
                OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Buyer FirebaseAuth Register : Fail");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could Not Register Your Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;

                        }
                        else
                            {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Buyer FirebaseAuth Register : Success");
                            Userdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(UserEmail);
                            final User user = new User(UserEmail, Password, Username, PhoneNumber, Address, ComfirmPassword);
                            Userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                        Userdatabase.setValue(user);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "FirebaseDatabase Add Buyer : Success");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Database Error");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }});

    }
```

Or firebase really not allow us to store email address as a primary key?

Comment: I had solved this

Answer (score 1):

**No** you cannot use special characters in your key value because it will break the functionalities of Firebase (especially the auto-built REST API).

If your tree has a node that contains a `/` in it's key, trying to access it via the REST API will be ambiguous :

```
http://yourproject.firebase.com/customers/mike/123
```

*Does it mean the property `123` from mike ? Or is it the node that has `mike/123` as key ? Impossible to know ...*

You should rely on auto-generated IDs for your customer node, and then store the email address in a field of this node :

```
users
  - h0r6TNCkEjMBGnYauwOdXhWt6oD3
    - email:mike@example.com
```

Comment: if you add a / to a string, it picks it up as an extra child. For instance if I say .child("car/ford") it will make a car node with a sub node of ford

Comment: @Janwilx72 can u create a chat room with me? cause i don't really understand

Comment: Yes, so the key will still not contain the character `/`. I don't know why `@` particularily is not accepted by Firebase, but I guess it will break another functionality if it was. Firebase already offers auto-generated IDs for users, OP should use them

Comment: @Choy is there something I wasn't clear about ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout how to use auto-generated Id?

Comment: @ArthurAttout I'm new to firebase, there is a lot I'm not clear about

Comment: Take a look at [the official Firebase documentation, under "create a user" section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), you will find useful informations as well as code examples in Java to use this feature

Comment: To use an auto generated id try the following @Choy 
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("Users").push().child("Email").setValue("john@doe.com");

The push() auto generates a key